# How does scala init a override field?

Tags: scala

I'm desire a print of `"my name - new name"` but `"my name - null"` placed:

```
trait SomeTrait {
  val name = "default name"
  println(s"my name - $name")
}    
class SomeClass extends SomeTrait {
  override val name: String = "new name"
}
object Main extends App {
  val constructTest = new SomeClass()
}
```

When executing Main,console output:
`my name - null`
Why print `null` rather then `new name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `name` to method like below to resolve this error. this because the super-classes are initialized before the sub-classes are initialized in scala and `val`s are initialized last after both superclasses and subclasses are initialized. In the example `name` cannot be `default name` when `SomeTrait` is initialized and then it becomes `"new name"` when `SomeClass` is initialized because `name` is supposed to be a immutable value. So the `name` value is initialized after all the constructors are completed.

```
trait SomeTrait {
  def name = "default name" //def instead of a val
  println(s"my name - $name")
}    

class SomeClass extends SomeTrait {
  override def name: String = "new name"
}
```

**Output:**

```
scala> new SomeClass()
my name - new name
res0: SomeClass = SomeClass@58f4b31a
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.BTW,why not print `my name - default name` if superclass first init in my code?

Comment: thats because `val`s are initialized last after both superclasses and subclasses are initialized.

Comment: OK, thanks again. Maybe read a `val` in trait init body is a bad idea.